# Structs to check login information in C

Tags: c, struct

I have to create a program that only allows 5 people to login with predetermined user ID's and passwords. I think defining them within a function then saving them in a struct would be the best way to do this. So far I have:

```
    struct nurse
{
    char id[5];
    char password[5][8];
}*record[5];

int main(void)
{

    record.id=1;
    strcopy(record.id, "username");
    strcopy(record.password, "password");

    printf("Please Enter your username: ");
    scanf("%s", id);
    if (id != username)
    {
        printf("Error. Record not found.");
    }
```

I'm unfortunately coming up with error messages saying "[Error] request for member 'id' in something not a structure or union" and the same error for 'password'.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can't program by trial & error. You must actually know what every line you write does. There is no function called `strcopy`. You didn't declare a variable called `id`. You have declared `record` as an array of unitialized pointers to structs and never set those pointers to point anywhere. And so on. There's no sorting this code out, you have to study arrays and pointers, then after that strings.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple errors in the code you show.

The first is that `record` is an array of five ***pointers*** to `struct nurse`.

It should be an array of structure object:

```
struct nurse { ... } record[5];  // No *, no pointers
```

The second problem is that you don't have a variable named `id` so

```
scanf("%s", id);
```

will not work.

The third problem is that you use the unknown function `strcopy`, when I believe you mean to use the standard [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) function.

The fourth problem is that the structures `id` member can only contain four-character strings, since the null-terminator needs one element. And you try to copy (in the example shown) a much longer string into that array.

The fifth problem is that you can't use `==` or `!=` to compare strings. You should use the [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function to compare strings.

The sixth problem is that the `password` member of the structure is an array of *arrays*, and you try to copy a string to `password` as it was a single string.

The seventh problem is that you treat the structures `id` member as both a string and as a single integer value. It can't be both.

There might be more problems, but these should be good enough to start with.

And all in all it seems you're missing some basic C knowledge, and could use a few books to read or classes to attend.

Answer (score 0):

The "not a structure or union" error is because the type of `record` in `record.id` is not a structure or union. `record` is an array of 5 pointers to `struct`, so the correct syntax would be `record[0]->id`. But you probably didn't want an array of pointers, so if you change the `*record[5]` to `record[5]`, you could access the `id` of the first record as `record[0].id` or `record->id`.

There are numerous other problems as well, on practically every line of the program, so I can only suggest spending more time learning the basics of C.

In general, C is a fairly concise and small language, so consider the meaning of each symbol carefully (e.g., an extra `*` makes all the difference) before you type it in. And instead of scattering literal numbers (like `5` and `8`) throughout your code, `#define` constants and use those instead. For example, it is now unclear whether `id[5]` has the `5` because you want there to be five ids in total, or because you want each individual id to be five characters long (in which case you are missing room for the NUL, or zero, terminator). For example:

```
#define NUM_RECORDS 5
#define ID_LENGTH 5
#define PASSWORD_LENGTH 8

struct nurse {
    char id[ID_LENGTH + 1];
    char password[PASSWORD_LENGTH + 1];
} record[NUM_RECORDS];
```

(You may later opt to use a more succinct style than this, but when getting started I believe it is better to be explicit.)